# How to get the string of SVG-Line as selected d3js-object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I created an svg-line by using the mouse in the following way:

On Mousedown:

```
drawObject = d3.select('#drawing').append('line')
        .classed(lineClass, true)
        .classed("graphic", true)
        .attr("x1", pointerOrigin.x)
        .attr("y1", pointerOrigin.y)
        .attr("x2", pointerOrigin.x)
        .attr("y2", pointerOrigin.y);
```

On MouseMove:

```
drawObject.attr("x2", pointerPosition.x)
        .attr("y2", pointerPosition.y);
```

So now I'd like to save this Line to database.
My idea was to save the string, as I did this with some grouped Elements bevor, that I created manually.

How do I get the string of the line like this:

```
<line xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="graphic" x1="1870" y1="-20" x2="1920" y2="-110" />
```

which is a result of the drawing and should be selected in drawObject.
Is there something like drawObject.innerHtml?

Comment: `outerHTML` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm...
This gives me undefined: console.log(drawObject.outerHTML);

Other idea was to get the type of the element and read the Attributes step by step. But Here I'm also confused...

Comment: `drawObject.node().outerHTML` You need to get the actual DOM node from the D3 selection.

Comment: Oh yes, that was the solution.

Thank you!